# extract email adresses from text file

Tags: email, text, replace, notepad++, sublimetext

I need to extract email adresses from a text file that contains the adresses with some names, `>` and `<` signs wrapping email adresses.

Is it possible to delete all strings that don't contain the `@` sign with sublime text, notepad++ or other?
This is an example (with false emails) of the text file I have :

```
...  
Cedric Pardit <c.pardi@inconu.com>, emmanuel > <emmanuel.brounidd7@fixe.com>, Claire et Francois <contact@jamaka.com>, Dominique Braud-Poloul <dbpoloul@hik.com>, michel.ours@yahoo.com, 
...
```

---

**UPDATE: Expected result**

```
 ...  
 c.pardi@inconu.com
 emmanuel.brounidd7@fixe.com
 contact@jamaka.com
 dbpoloul@hik.com
 michel.ours@yahoo.com, 
 ...
```

Comment: What is the expected result with your example?

Comment: @M42 updated my question with what I need at the end

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use regex to get the email addresses between `<>` tags, like so:

```
(?<=\<)(.*)(?=\>+)
```

Assuming only email addresses will be enclosed in `<>`.

#### UPDATE

This will match all email addresses in the file, regardless of position:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+@[A-Za-z0-9_]+?\.[A-Za-z]{2,6})
```

replace with `$&\n` which matches the email address and adds a newline.

Comment: well all emails aren't eclosed in those tags, `>` signs appear in wierd positions. I don't know where this text file comes from but it is very messy... sorry about that

Comment: @chadocat - You're only interested in the email addresses..?

Comment: Oh, well that's not that hard. Updated answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with regex. I'll have to learn about it is there an online tool that could help me?

Comment: @chadocat - Sure. [Here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is a site that talks about regular expression and [here](http://regexpal.com/) is an online tool to test your regex's.

Comment: Thx a lot for taking time to answer, your regex expression seems to work the tester you linked wraps the emails nicely. Is it possible to extract the "output" of the regex somehow from regexpal?

Comment: @chadocat - You're welcome, glad I could help. There is another online tool [here](http://www.myregextester.com/) that has a lot more options and you could do a replace and choose your output type there as well.

Comment: The regex in the Update above does not match underscores (`_`) or second level domains such as `.co.uk`

Answer (score 2):

I'd do simply:

```
<?(\S+@\S+)>?
```

This will match all addresses enclosed or not in `<`  and `>`.

Comment: This also outputs the `>` signs and comas when there is no space between email and them.

Comment: @web-tiki this option is allmost perfect, but you can open sublime and search the "<" and ">" simbol and delete it then use the <?(\S+@\S+)>? and will select every email great solution

Answer (score 1):

You can extract all the email id from a file

```
     BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new 
     FileReader("C://Users//..........your file name"));
     String line="";
     Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9_.]*@[A-Za-z0-9]+
     ([.A-Za-z])+"); 

    while((line=bf.readLine()) != null){
    Matcher mt = pt.matcher(line);
    while(mt.find()){
        System.out.println(mt.group());
    }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

using Notepad++
I would start by replacing all spaces and commas with a newline (Search Mode extended and then use \n) 
Then you'll have all the email addresses on separate lines. 
From there you just record a macro that finds the @ and cut that line and then a new text file, this can be done by having 2 text files open and switching between them using Ctrl-Tab

And replace the < and > 
This might not be the easiest way but I would probably do it that way